# How to obtain the media-id from an instagram image url

Tags: api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to obtain the media id of an image so I can use this to gather insight information from a new API call: GET /{ig-media-id}/insights?metric={metric}

I have tried retrieving the media id using this request: http://api.instagram.com/oembed?callback=&url={image url} ... however, the media_id in the response is not valid for the insights API call.

Does anyone know how to get a valid media id or how to use the one returned in the above request?

Answer (score 0):

<meta property="al:ios:url" content=
found in the meta property of the page view-source

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

adding to the earlier answer
inspect element >> search for "al:ios:url" >> it's in the string followed by content =

-> instagram://media?id=2905947356079086246

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).